# Angular BehaviorSubject undefined at initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a new `BehaviorSubject` of type `ICar` (defined by me) in a service and put `null` or `undefined` by default. If I'm updating the type to `ICar | undefined`, I will get an error at function `getCar()` because is complaining about the return type. Is there any workaround to resolve this issue?

My code:

```
export interface ICar{
 id:number,
 name: string,
}
//service:
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarService {
    private car$ = new BehaviorSubject<ICar>(null); //error

    constructor() {
    }

    setCar(car: ICar) {
        this.car$.next(car);
    }

    getCar(): Observable<ICar> {
        return this.car$;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have strict typing on in your tsconfig (I think this is on by default) you have to declare the type as `ICar | null`, something like `new BehaviorSubjec<ICar | null>(null)`

Comment: Yes, but this is forcing me to adapt getCar's return type to BehaviorSubject<ICar | null> and I don't want this.

Comment: you can create a default ICar

Comment: You may consider using `Subject` if you don't want to initialize the value. `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` are required to intialize with a value.

Comment: What's the _behaviour_ that you want? Creating a `BehaviorSubject` suggests it should _immediately_ emit a value, the default you pass (currently `null`, which indeed means your subjects receive either an `ICar` or `null`). If you want to _always_ emit an `ICar`, either the default value needs to implement that interface or you shouldn't have that default value (and therefore not a subject that requires one).

Answer (score 0):

If your `car$` can be null only at the beginning, and you need `behaviorSubject` only to store the previously loaded value, you can use something like:

```
private carSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ICar>(null);
private car$ = carSubject.pipe(filter(car => !!car) car is ICar);
```

in this filter operator, you are filtering all nullish values and after that saying that `car` is of type `ICar`.

And, just as a suggestion to think about: maybe it will be better to make a small rewrite of this service. For example, you can prevent changing values of the subject from outside (current implementation will pass a reference to a subject out from the service).

Maybe to something like that:

```
class CarService implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly car = new BehaviorSubject<ICar | null>(null);

  // from the property below you can get your subject values but as 
  // an observable, so it will be closed for .next from outside
  readonly car$ = car.pipe(filter(car => !!car) car is ICar);

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.car.complete(); // <- do not forget to close your subject;
  }

  setCar(car: ICar): void {
    this.car.next(car);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open your `tsoconfig.ts` you could add property `"strictNullChecks": false,`. Although I don't know if it is wise thing to do.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

The real solution would be to simply say that the value/type can be empty, `ICar | null`

OR

You can use Subject instead of a BehaviourSubject and publish only valid ICar to that stram